# Deadlock while parallel insert using `INSERT INTO <table> WITH (TABLOCK) (columns) VALUES ()` syntax

Tags: sql-server, database, multiprocessing, pyodbc, locks

I'm trying to bulk load a large dataset into an SQL Server Heap (table with non-clustered index) using multi-processing and `pyodbc`. Each process attempts to insert an equal chunk to the heap. Here's the insert statement I'm using:

```
sql_expr = "INSERT INTO <DestinationTable> WITH (TABLOCK) (<Columns>) VALUES(...)"
cursor.fast_executemany = True
cursor.executemany(sql_expr, values)
```

The program terminates with this error:

*[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Transaction (Process ID 78) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. (1205) (SQLExecute)*

[Microsoft's Data Loading Performance Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd425070(v=sql.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#insert--select) only has an example with the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO <DestinationTable> (<Columns>) WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT <Columns> FROM <SomeStatement>
```

Notice the difference between the two syntaxes.

I have confirmed I have no index on the heap/table. Can someone tell why this is resulting in a deadlock?

Comment: have you tried to remove TABLOCK-hint ?

Comment: I want to use `TABLOCK` because it enables minimal logging and can be used during parallel insert statements.

Comment: totally agree with you, but "Each process attempts to insert an equal chunk to the heap".If the first process has locked the whole table what the second process will do?

Comment: As `VALUES` means that you are inserting a maximum of 1,000 rows why are you caring about it getting a parallel plan and minimal logging?

Comment: `TABLOCK` allows parallel insert into a heap while ensuring minimal logging.

Comment: I updated the question with info about `pyodbc` package that I'm using.

Comment: Deadlock aside, this can't work the way you intend. A plain `INSERT` does not allow for parallel bulk inserts from *different processes*, even with `TABLOCK`. This is also described in the docs: the lock taken is an exclusive lock, not a bulk update lock. If you want a parallel bulk insert from different processes, you need to leverage the native bulk copy functionality. In .NET this would be `SqlBulkCopy`, AFAICT bulk copying (`INSERT BULK`, not to be confused with `BULK INSERT`) is not surfaced in pyodbc. An alternative would be invoking `bcp`, though there's overhead generating files.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thanks for the input, explains a lot. I have used `BCP` for this use case, however, we wanted to see if this is possible with `pyodbc`.